# Multi-level parent-child nodes relationship

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an original table with 2 columns, parent_node_id (parent) and node_id (child) and I want to get a final output of 3 columns: "root", "internal" and "leaf" nodes. I want to use group_concat() and group by to achieve the expected output in the picture provided.

This is the original table from the tree diagram in the picture provided.

| parent_node_id | node_id |
| --- | --- |
| NULL | 10 |
| NULL | 20 |
| 10 | 1 |
| 10 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 2 | 4 |
| 20 | 5 |
| 20 | 6 |
| 6 | 7 |
| 6 | 8 |
| 8 | 9 |

[question case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wfhu6.jpg)

I need to get an output that looks like this:

| root | internal | leaf |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 2 | 1,3,4 |
| 20 | 6,8 | 5,7,9 |

I tried creating 3 CTEs to get individual root, internal and leaf nodes. However, I am unable to create a sub relational table that gives the relationship with the parent and root nodes.

Here is what i tried:

```
    select
    m.node_id as root,
    group_concat(distinct i.node_id order by i.node_id separator ',') as internal,
    group_concat(distinct l.node_id order by l.node_id separator ',') as leaf
from craig_test.test m
left join craig_test.test r on m.node_id = r.node_id and r.parent_node_id is null
left join craig_test.test i on m.node_id = i.node_id and i.node_id in (select parent_node_id from craig_test.test where parent_node_id is not null)
left join craig_test.test l on m.node_id = l.node_id and l.node_id not in (select parent_node_id from craig_test.test where parent_node_id is not null)
-- where m.parent_node_id is null
group by 1
```

Comment: Removed conflicting database product tags. Pls add the one back that you actually use.

Comment: I have updated the information and included an additional image link on what I have tried

Comment: Please don't link to images - add all information to your question as editable text, so that someone can copy it if they need to

Comment: yes i have inlcuded the tables from the images into the question as editable text. the image is just for illustration purposes

Comment: alright, I have changed it. The question is filled with all the information anyone needs. Is someone able to solve this question?

Comment: I have seen and tried the recursive method, but I am not sure how to implement it as I am a novice. I humbly request a kind soul to provide a SQL solution to assist me.

Comment: Having records like `<parent_node>, NULL` for leaves can come in handy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are more efficient ways of doing this, but this will provide the result you requested:

```sql
// build list of all nodes with their parent and whether they have children
WITH RECURSIVE hierarchy (root_node_id, node_id, has_children) AS (
    SELECT
        t.node_id,
        t.node_id,
        EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM test WHERE parent_node_id = t.node_id)
    FROM test t
    WHERE t.parent_node_id IS NULL

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        h.root_node_id,
        t.node_id,
        EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM test WHERE parent_node_id = t.node_id)
    FROM test t
    JOIN hierarchy h ON t.parent_node_id = h.node_id
)
SELECT
    root_node_id AS root,
    GROUP_CONCAT(IF(has_children AND root_node_id <> node_id, node_id, NULL)) AS internal,
    GROUP_CONCAT(IF(NOT has_children, node_id, NULL)) AS leaf
FROM hierarchy
GROUP BY root_node_id;
```

The CTE builds:

| root_node_id | node_id | has_children |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 10 | 1 |
| 20 | 20 | 1 |
| 10 | 1 | 0 |
| 10 | 2 | 1 |
| 20 | 5 | 0 |
| 20 | 6 | 1 |
| 10 | 3 | 0 |
| 10 | 4 | 0 |
| 20 | 7 | 0 |
| 20 | 8 | 1 |
| 20 | 9 | 0 |

And then the GROUP BY query outputs:

| root | internal | leaf |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 2 | 1,3,4 |
| 20 | 6,8 | 5,7,9 |

Comment: Thank you so much! It works! I'm going to break it down and study it to understand it fully.